# SonarQube Technical Debt

Tags: sonarqube, technical-debt

I've got a question about SonarQube and the technical debt.

The official [SonarQube 4.3 Release Notes](http://www.sonarqube.org/sonarqube-4-3-in-screenshots/#more-10185) says "Now SonarQube displays debt not in fractional days but in days, hours and (where appropriate) minutes." But I wonder if there is a possibility to do the same for days and month or at least years.

I would appreciate it very much if it would be possible to configure the time unit.

As example: we have a helicopter view where a timeline, size metrics, issues and technical debt are shown. All projects are summarized to one project via the "views plugin" to do so.

But here comes the problem: the technical debt is shown as "39,782 days". Years would come in handy here.

Is there a possible to change the shown time unit or not?

thanks to everyone who is posting an answer! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hours/minutes/seconds breakdown is fixed, as of SQ 4.4 there is no configuration option to allow larger units.

At these amounts of technical debt, the raw value is probably not very significant.

Keeping "working days" as the coarse grain unit allows you to get a grasp of the amount of work to be done to get rid of the debt, but with such a huge value, it is probably better to concentrate on differential values (e.g debt added/removed over a given period).